# Unable to load a .ogg file

Tags: python-3.x, file

Here is a small part of my program I am working on. I am trying to load the .ogg file and play the audio.

```
import pygame


HERO="hero.png"
LASER="laser.png"
MUSIC = pygame.mixer.Sound("Closing-Music.ogg")
MUSIC.play()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/Account/PycharmProjects/PyGame/Game 2/gsettings.py", line 6, in <module>
MUSIC = pygame.mixer.Sound("Closing-Music.ogg")
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'Closing-Music.ogg'
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's looking in the right place? Try using a full, absolute path to the file. Do you have the appropriate codecs installed - ie. can your system play the file *at all*?

Comment: @Edward yes I am able to play the file. The odd thing is that I have other files, like the images, and those are in the same exact folder as the .ogg file. They are able to be loaded in fine, but not the .ogg file. How would I use a direct path to the file?

Comment: @Edward Oh I figured it out. I should have put pygame.mixer.init() at the beginning. It ended up working